# Amazon S3 temporary URL to image works in IE and Firefox but not Safari

Tags: safari, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, right-aws

I'm using Amazon S3 to host images.  The S3 bucket is private, so I generate a temporary URL  (using [Right AWS](http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/)) with a 5-minute expiry to allow the image to be rendered.  The URL looks like this (note: URL below will not work):

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443/attachments%2F30%2Fsmall.png?Signature=J%2BXzQd95myCNv0Re8arMhuTFSvk%3D&Expires=1235511662&AWSAccessKeyId=1K3MW21E6T8LWBY94C01
```

This works fine, and I can paste the URL into Firefox and the image is displayed.  Same for IE.  However, when I try it in Safari the URL appears to resolve but no image is displayed.  Similarly, if I try and use the URL in the **src** attribute of an **IMG** tag on a web page, nothing is rendered by Safari (fine in all other browsers), e.g:

[alt text http://lylo.co.uk/screenshot.png](http://lylo.co.uk/screenshot.png)

Has anyone seen this behaviour before and can you point out what, if anything, I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't seen this myself - do you maybe have your Safari set up not to download images ?

Comment: No, Safari is absolutely fine.  It's only these particular S3 URLs which won't resolve.  I'm genuinely baffled.

Comment: When you download the image with FF, does it display in Safari? When you access the image via http instead of https, does it still not work in Safari? If so, please provide a dump of the network traffic (Install wireshark, Capture->Interfaces...->Start, load img in Safari, Capture->Stop, File->Save)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of digging around in the S3 library I'm using I have found the problem here.

When you upload a file to S3 you have to set the `Content-Type` header.  In my situation I was uploading two files, one was an original PDF file with a Content-Type of `application/pdf`, the other was a thumbnail preview in PNG format.  The library I was using to upload to S3 does set the `Content-Type` header, but it was setting the header to `application/pdf` for both the original PDF and the PNG thumbnail.

It seems that Firefox and IE will happily render a PNG image from S3 even though it has the wrong `Content-Type` header, whereas Safari doesn't like this at all and consequently won't render the image.

So, patching the S3 library I'm using such that the correct `Content-Type` header is correctly set on the PNG thumbnails solved the issue.

Phew.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is not recognized by AWS:

```
...attachments%2F30%2Fsmall.png...
```

It should actually read:

```
...attachments/30/small.png...
```

Firefox **will** replace all URL-encoded entities (prior to the '?' query marker) with their corresponding ASCII representations before actually submitting the request (i.e. Firefox will replace `%2F` with `/` in the example above), whereas Safari might not.  AWS will likely reply with HTTP 404 to Safari in such circumstances.

Make sure that your URL is well formed for AWS.  Study carefully any differences between the URL that Firefox has in its address bar after the image is *successfully* retrieved, vs. the URL that Safari has in its address bar after the image *fails* to be retrieved.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I wonder what servers do weird things when presented with %2F in the file name.

Comment: I have tried unescaping the URL and it makes no difference -- it still doesn't render in Safari but does in IE and Firefox.